# how to run history -a command at regular intervals automatically?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-history

I am using bash shell and I execute `history -a` command once in a while manually. My typical shell session lasts for weeks if not for months and I rarely exit my shell session. Thus, I force writing my current session history to bash_history using `history -a` once in a while. I am thinking of writing an automated script to execute `history -a` regularly once a day. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key at least once a day, then a PROMPT_COMMAND-based solution could work for you:

```bsh
save_history_daily () {
  # if the current time is more than a day's-worth of seconds newer than
  # the modification time of $HISTFILE, then run 'history -a'

  if (( $(printf '%(%s)T' -1) - 86400 > $(stat -c %Y "$HISTFILE") ))
  then 
    history -a
  fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND
save_history_daily"
```

This relies on bash version bash-4.2-alpha or newer for the `printf %(...)T` feature; here, I'm using the `-1` argument to it to retrieve the current time in seconds-since-the-epoch. If you have an older bash version, you could replace that bit with a call to `date`: `$(date +%s)`. Bash versions as of bash-5.0-alpha have the EPOCHSECONDS variable available, which would be slightly more efficient.

I've copied the embedded-newline PROMPT_COMMAND assignment idea from [one of Gilles' answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369064/117549); it appends the new function call to any existing value(s) that were already defined.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `history` is a Bash built-in command and it affects the session it is run. As far as I know, you can't run a history command from another session to save recent commands that have not yet been saved.

One solution may be to modify your `PROMPT_COMMAND` environment variable to run `history -a` at every command entry. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save a shells history from a script. Not directly anyway.

This is a mostly untested idea.

The `bash` shell ignores the `QUIT` signal, both as an interactive shell and as a non-interactive shell.

This means that a trap could be install to catch the `QUIT` signal.  This could be done from the shell's startup file for interactive shell sessions, i.e. in `~/.bashrc`. The trap would simply call `history -a`:

```bsh
trap 'history -a' QUIT
```

The `QUIT` signal could then be sent to a shell session to have it save its history.  Using `pkill`, you could even send it to *all* `bash` sessions that you currently run:

```bsh
pkill -QUIT -U "$LOGNAME" bash
```

This could be done from a cron job.

Note that I haven't actually tested this to any degree other than to see that it *appears* to be working.  The only niggle is that `^\` appears at the prompt in the shells that gets signaled in this manner. I'm also just *assuming* that if many shells save their history *at the same time*, then this is done in an intelligent way as to avoid intermingled writes.

---

Personally, I would probably go with using `history -a` in `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead:

```bsh
PROMPT_COMMAND+="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+;}history -a"
```

or

```bsh
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND;}history -a"
```

(These append `history -a` to the value of `PROMPT_COMMAND` and delimits it with `;` if the variable already had a non-empty value.)

This would save the history just before showing the next prompt.  There would probably not be any sort of noticeable decrease in performance from doing this at every prompt.